# sqlserver Query time taking

Tags: sql-server

I am executing below query. It takes 80 seconds for just 17 records.

can any body tell me reason if knows. I have already tried with Indexes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.i_UserID,
                u.vch_LoginName,
                t.vch_PreviousEmailAddress AS 'vch_EmailAddress',
                u.vch_DisplayName,
                t.d_TransactionDate AS 'd_DateAdded',
                'Old' AS 'vch_RecordStatus'
           FROM tblEmailTransaction t
     INNER JOIN tblUser u 
             ON t.i_UserID = u.i_UserID
          WHERE t.vch_PreviousEmailAddress LIKE '%kala%'
```

Comment: Post your Actual Execution Plan and we'll be able to see what's taking the time.

Comment: `WHERE t.vch_PreviousEmailAddress Like '%kala%'` **[Non-SARGable condition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/799604/5070879)**

Answer (score 1):

Change collation for `vch_PreviousEmailAddress` column on `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`

Create covered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
ON dbo.tblEmailTransaction (vch_PreviousEmailAddress)
    INCLUDE (i_UserID, d_TransactionDate)
GO
```

And have fun with this query:

```
SELECT t.i_UserID,
       u.vch_LoginName,
       t.vch_PreviousEmailAddress AS vch_EmailAddress,
       u.vch_DisplayName,
       t.d_TransactionDate AS d_DateAdded,
       'Old' AS vch_RecordStatus
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT i_UserID,
                    vch_PreviousEmailAddress,
                    d_TransactionDate
    FROM dbo.tblEmailTransaction
    WHERE vch_PreviousEmailAddress LIKE '%kala%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
) t
JOIN dbo.tblUser u ON t.i_UserID = u.i_UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

One other thing, which I find useful in solving problems like this:

Try running the following script.  It will tell you which indexes you could ask to your SQL Server database, which would make the most (positive) improvement.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT TOP 100 
  ROUND(s.avg_total_user_cost * s.avg_user_impact * (s.user_seeks + s.user_scans),0) AS 'Total Cost',
  s.avg_user_impact,
  d.statement AS 'Table name',
  d.equality_columns, 
  d.inequality_columns,
  d.included_columns,
  'CREATE INDEX [IndexName] ON ' + d.statement + ' ( ' 
     + case when (d.equality_columns IS NULL OR d.inequality_columns IS NULL)
       then ISNULL(d.equality_columns, '') + ISNULL(d.inequality_columns, '')
       else ISNULL(d.equality_columns, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(d.inequality_columns, '')
     end + ' ) '
     + CASE WHEN d.included_columns IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'INCLUDE ( ' + d.included_columns + ' )' end AS 'CREATE INDEX command'
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups g,
     sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats s, 
     sys.dm_db_missing_index_details d 
WHERE d.database_id = DB_ID() 
AND s.group_handle = g.index_group_handle 
AND d.index_handle = g.index_handle
ORDER BY [Total Cost] DESC
```

The right-hand column displays the CREATE INDEX command which you'd need to run, to create that index.

[image: Missing indexes]

This one of those lifesaver scripts, which I run on our in-house databases once ever so often.

But yes, in your example, this is just likely to tell you that you need an index on the `vch_PreviousEmailAddress` field in your `tblEmailTransaction` table.

Answer (score 0):

The probable bottleneck are 2:

1. Missing Index on tblEmailTransaction.i_UserID: Check if the table has the index
2. Missing Index on tblUser.i_UserID: Check if the table has the index
3. Like Statement: Like statement is know to be not good in performance, as Devart suggested, try to specify collection in this way:

   ```
    WHERE vch_PreviousEmailAddress LIKE '%kala%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
   ```

To have a better view on your query, You have to run this command with your query:

```
SET IO STATISTICS ON
```

It will write all the IO Access that the query does and the we can see what happen.

Just a final question ?
How many rows contains the two tables?

Ciao